# Low End AC is 150+ PSI

Tags: ac, mazda, mazda-3

I drive a 2012 MazdaSpeed 3. A couple weeks ago I noticed that my AC was blowing hot air. I went to recharge the AC as I figured I may have had a leak and lost coolant but turned out that my low end port had over 150 PSI reading on my AC Recharging gauge.

Could this be something to do with the AC Compressor itself? Bad clutch?

If neither of the above, what may be a solution to this problem? Discharge the system and recharge to proper pressure?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Ive got a 2008 Mazda 3 and my A/C just quit. In my case it was a dead compressor clutch coil. Resistance across coil = infinity. Easiest way to measure resistance is by pulling out A/C relay and probe thru output circuit. Should be 5k ohms

Comment: 150 psig is definitely too high for low pressure in an operating system, sounds like a static pressure you would read in a place like Death Valley. Is the clutch hub on the compressor clutch rotating when AC is on?